# How to rearrange to get from the first line to the next?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I am having some difficulty rearranging to get from the first line to the next.

Any help would be much appreciated!

$$s\sqrt{1-s^2}\,(A_{kk}-A_{ll})=(2s^2-1)\,A_{lk} $$

$$s^2=\frac12\left(1\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{(A_{kk}-A_{ll})^2}{(A_{kk}-A_{ll})^2+4A_{lk}^2}}\right) $$

Comment: You may take the square of both side, and solve a quadratic equation with respect to the unknown $s^2$.

Comment: Would you please be able to write it in an answer as I can't seem to get it to work?

Comment: Sure, just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the square of the original equation
$$
s\sqrt{1-s^2}\left(A_{kk}-A_{ll}\right)=\left(2s^2-1\right)A_{lk},
$$
and we have
$$
s^2\left(1-s^2\right)\left(A_{kk}-A_{ll}\right)^2=\left(2s^2-1\right)^2A_{lk}^2.
$$
Open the parentheses containing $s$, and we obtain
$$
\left(s^2-s^4\right)\left(A_{kk}-A_{ll}\right)^2=\left(4s^4-4s^2+1\right)A_{lk}^2.
$$
Rearrange the terms with respect to $s$, and we have
$$
\left(4A_{lk}^2+\left(A_{ll}-A_{kk}\right)^2\right)s^4-\left(4A_{lk}^2+\left(A_{ll}-A_{kk}\right)^2\right)s^2+A_{lk}^2=0,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
s^4-s^2+\frac{A_{lk}^2}{4A_{lk}^2+\left(A_{ll}-A_{kk}\right)^2}=0.
$$
Obviously, this is a quadratic equation with respect to $s^2$, i.e., $a\left(s^2\right)^2+b\left(s^2\right)+c=0$. Thus
\begin{align}
s^2&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{4A_{lk}^2}{4A_{lk}^2+\left(A_{ll}-A_{kk}\right)^2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{\frac{\left(A_{ll}-A_{kk}\right)^2}{4A_{lk}^2+\left(A_{ll}-A_{kk}\right)^2}}\right).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$s\sqrt{1-s^2}(A_{kk}-A_{ll})=(2s^2-1)\,A_{lk}$$
$$\tag{square both sides}(-s^4+s^2) (A_{kk}-A_{ll})^2 = (4s^4 - 4s^2 + 1)A_{lk}^2$$
$$\tag{rearrange} s^4 \big(4A_{lk}^2 + (A_{kk}-A_{ll})^2\big) - s^2\big( 4A_{lk}^2 + (A_{kk}-A_{ll})^2   \big) + A_{lk}^2= 0$$
$$\tag{sub $x^2 = s, a = 4A_{lk}^2 + (A_{kk}-A_{ll})^2$} ax^2 - ax + A_{lk}^2 = 0$$
$$\tag{quadratic formula} x = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4aA_{lk}^2}}{2a} $$
$$\tag{factor $a$ under square root} x= \frac{1}{2}\left(1 \pm \sqrt{\frac{a^2-4aA_{lk}^2}{a^2}} \right)$$
$$\tag{cancel $a$ in root and resub} s^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{\frac{(A_{kk}-A_{ll})^2}{(A_{kk}-A_{ll})^2+4A_{lk}^2}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

As hypernova pointed out, we can take the sqare on both side and elaborate:

[Link to the algebraic passages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDRr6.jpg)

You can then substitute the expression of *a* in the last equation and find the result.

Hope this helps.

D.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, I'll take a look at that asap.